How to determine correct connection parameters in docker for a postgres database
I'm learning docker and trying to connect a node application with a Postgres database. But I cannot resolve the following error when I start the containers:

NOTE: Update error AFTER adding the healthcheck section suggested by Hans Killian.

I already know that the issue is the connection to Postgres. The problem is that I do not understand precisely which parameters I should use or how to obtain them. That is my confusion. I've been following several tutorials, and all of them, even if they gave rich information, skip that part, probably thinking it is too obvious. I have tried several combinations (the usual localhost, 0.0.0.0, etc) to no avail. As you can see, there are two images, one for the application and another for Postgres, so one application is trying to connect to the other.
Next, I will list all the details I think are essential. I'll appreciate any guidance, any "kid, you must look to this place," that you can give me.
The folder structure is the following:

The database Dockerfile is as follows:
FROM postgres:16-alpine
COPY 00-init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

The Dockerfile from server is as follows:
FROM node:21

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

package.js is as follows:
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Backend",
  "main": "./src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node .",
    "dev": "nodemon ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "pg": "^8.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
  }
}

And finally docker-compose.yaml is as follows:
services:
   database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    command: "-p ${POSTGRES_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - database-v:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    container_name: container-pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
       database:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    restart: unless-stopped
  server:
    image: server:1.0.0
    container_name: ${SERVER_HOST}
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - server-v-node-modules:/server/node_modules
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_started
  volumes:
    database-v:
      name: "database-v"
    server-v-node-modules:
      name: "server-v-node-modules"

The .env files containing the environment variables is as follows:
SERVER_HOST="server-c"
SERVER_PORT="3000"

POSTGRES_HOST="postgres-c"
POSTGRES_PORT="5432"
POSTGRES_USER="admin@example.com"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root"
POSTGRES_DB="app-db"

and the server.js, inside server/src folder, connect to the database this way:
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require("cors")
const PORT = 3000;
        
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB
})
        
async function connectToDatabase() {
  const client = await pool.connect();
    try {
      const response = await client.query("SELECT * FROM users");
      const { rows } = response;
      console.log(rows)
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    } finally {
      client.release();
    }
  }
       
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Vianni Server started on port ${PORT}`);
  connectToDatabase()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to Postgres!"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Error connection to Postgres!", err));
});

and finally the command I'm using to  start the app is
docker compose up

Also, if you see any other error or place where I could improve, I'd really appreciate it if you mentioned it.
My best regards.

Looks like you start the database server after you have tried to connect to the database server. That's the wrong order, you first have to start the database server before a client can connect to it.

See this question (the answer by VInicius Chan) to see how to add a healthcheck to the postgres container and have your server wait for it to have a healthy status.

This was already mentioned in the comments, but you have a dependency problem: your application is attempting to connect to the database before the database is ready to accept connections. You have declared the following dependency:
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_started

But this is completely useless because the condition is satisfied as soon as the postgres container starts; it doesn't know whether or not the database is ready to process connections, so your dependent containers start before postgres is ready.
To correct the problem, you need to:

Add a healthcheck to the postgres container to identify when it is ready, and
Change your dependency from service_started to service_healthy

The healthcheck should look something like this:
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

And the dependency should look like this:
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

The complete compose.yaml would look like:
volumes:
  database-v:
    name: database-v
  server-v-node-modules:
    name: server-v-node-modules

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}
    command: -p ${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - database-v:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  pgadmin:
    container_name: container-pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    restart: unless-stopped
  server:
    image: server:1.0.0
    container_name: ${SERVER_HOST}
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - server-v-node-modules:/server/node_modules
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

And running docker compose up results in your application successfully connecting to the database:
$ docker compose up
.
.
.
postgres-c         | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres-c         | This user must also own the server process.
.
.
.
postgres-c         | 2024-10-11 14:08:51.080 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
server-c           |
server-c           | > server@0.1.0 dev
server-c           | > nodemon .
.
.
.
server-c           | Connected to Postgres!
.
.
.

